# Is it possible to "overload" the type deduced by auto for custom types in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, type-deduction

Not sure whether "overloading" is the proper term, however I am curious whether it is possible to make expressions of a given type to automatically convert to other type?

Possible motivation:

```
template <typename T> Property {
// implement the desired behavior
};

class SomeClass {
// ...
Property<SomeType> someProperty;
// ...
};

SomeClass someInstance{ ... };
auto someVariable = someInstance.someProperty; // Type of some variable will be Property<T>
```

If I take some effort, I can disallow constructor and assignment of Property and use

```
SomeType someVariable = someInstance.someProperty;
```

However, I am curious whether it is possible to make

```
auto someVariable = someInstance.someProperty;
```

such the the type of `someVariable` is `SomeType` and not `Property<SomeType>`.

Thanks.

Comment: Since C++20 there is __Type constraint__ `auto` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto#Type_constraint but I am not sure if this will do what you want.

Comment: Afaik this is impossible. You could perhaps overload a unary operator for doing this with only one additional char though: `template<class T> struct Property { T m_value; decltype(auto) operator+() const { return m_value; } }; ... auto someVariable = +someInstance.someProperty;`. Note that this could result in unexpected behaviour when applying the `+` operator, if the type provides an unary `+` operator that doesn't result in the identity...

Comment: I think overloading `()` will do same and be more useful… and C++ “properties” often have `()` anyway…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. `auto` will deduce to the (decayed) type of the right-hand side and there is no way to affect this deduction.

You can however of course write a function template `X` such that

```
auto someVariable = X(someInstance.someProperty);
```

will result in the type you want, basically without any restrictions on the possible type transformations made by `X`.

Comment: Basically I can always add something like `operator ()` at the end to the property definition… However I was curious whether it was possible to make `Property<T>` and to behave like Swift and C# properties without (without the braces). While it seems like one can get close, it breaks when using `auto`…

Comment: @MyrddinKrustowski Don't write C# in C++.

Comment: Swift and Kotlin have them too… Would not say they are deal breakers, but it is useful syntactic sugar…